# Usage of TYPED-DATA and CAPABILITY-DATA in the OSI Session Protocol (X.225)

Tags: session, osi

ITU-T Recommendation X.215 describes the "capability data exchange" functional unit, which is realized via the `CAPABILITY-DATA` SPDU described in ITU-T Recommendation X.225. I can read in the specification that its purpose is so that data transfer SPDUs may be sent outside of an activity, but why is it called `CAPABILITY-DATA`? Is there some lore behind its name that is obsolete?

As for the `TYPED-DATA` SPDU, I don't understand its purpose at all. The specification says that:

> The typed data functional unit enables the SS-users to transfer data in a manner which is not subject to the control
> imposed by the availability of the data token.

But isn't the point of tokens to restrict dialogue? It seems like the `TYPED-DATA` SPDU completely contradicts one of the main purposes of the session layer. For that matter, why is it called "typed data"? Is it because it is meant to be real-time user data, like what somebody might type on a keyboard, or something like that?